# Why does my python code display things that I don't want?

Tags: python

I don't think the title of this question is suitable, sorry. So I want to ask, I happen to be a beginner in python, before I was a PHP user. This problem arises because python always displays an error when it does not find what it is looking for, as in the code below:

```
import re

txt = "The rain mantap bang in Spain"
x = re.findall("mantap jiwa", txt)

if x[0] == 'mantap jiwa':
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./prog.py", line 6, in 
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Why doesn't python display "not found"? why do you have to display an error, how do you make python display "not found"?

Comment: mantap jiwa is not in `txt`, so it returns an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to access the first element of `x` (by saying `x[0]`) raises an exception because `x` is empty, so there is no first element:

```
>>> txt = "The rain mantap bang in Spain"
>>> x = re.findall("mantap jiwa", txt)
>>> x
[]
```

The best way to test whether something is in a collection (list, set, etc) is to simply use the `in` operator:

```
if 'mantap jiwa' in x:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Since `x` will always be empty if you didn't find a match, checking the actual contents of the match isn't necessary for what you're doing.  You can just ask whether x contains anything at all:

```
if len(x) >= 0:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

```
if x:  # truthy check -- x is "true" if it has at least one element
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Or you could use your original code but catch the exception:

```
try:
    if x[0] == 'mantap jiwa':
        print("found")
    else:
        raise IndexError()
except IndexError:
    print("not found")
```